# Diable automatic pointing stick recalibration

Tags: windows-7, mouse, calibration

I have a Toshiba Tecra R840-S8450 running Windows 7.  I prefer using the accupoint (eraser-looking pointing stick thing) over the touch pad or a separate mouse.  Periodically, however, it has a really annoying habit of causing the mouse cursor to drift on its own for a few seconds.  Based on my research this appears to be caused by the stick recalibrating itself.  I am able to reproduce this by holding the stick steadily off-center for a few seconds until the cursor stops.  When I let go, the cursor drifts in the opposite direction for a few seconds since it thinks it is no longer centered.

Is there a way to disable the automatic recalibration of the stick?  Ideally, there would be a way to manually tell it to recalibrate.

Comment: It doesn't really warrent the name “Accupoint”. ¬_¬ I’m surprised people *prefer* it to other devices; I remember using a joystick as a mouse with my Tandy and hating it. Anyway, Toshiba says to [just let it happen](http://web1.toshiba.ca/support/isg/tsb/en/view.asp?docid=TSB000592). ಠ_ಠ Others have suggested [cleaning it](http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=14401) to make the calibration happen faster or even [disabling it](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/threads/19494/) so that it doesn’t interfere with other pointing devices.

Comment: The main reason I prefer it is because I don't have to move my hand away from the keyboard.  Not even down to the touch pad.  Yes, I am _that_ lazy (though, I like to think of it as being efficient).  I saw that Toshiba page before I posted the question.  I was just hoping that things may have changed in the 15 years since it was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as it's ingrained into the hardware itself. The trick is to just wait for it to complete calibration and not touch the mouse and also resist the urge to hold your finger on it.

Reference: [Toshiba](http://web1.toshiba.ca/support/isg/tsb/en/view.asp?docid=TSB000592)

Comment: I had a feeling that it might be the hardware doing the recalibration, but couldn't find anything to confirm that.